# Flask-Mail on Google App Engine Flexible ENV

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, flask-mail

I'm trying to get Flask-Mail setup on in Flexible ENV on Google App Engine. Flask-Mail works on my localhost using the credentials for a domain I am trying to use to send the mail. However, when using it on GAE through my API it returns a 502 error, however it shows no error messages in the logs or console. Going through the documentation for GAE Flexible it doesn't mention anything about NOT being able to use it, however it doesn't show how one would setup Flask-Mail either.

I have this..

```
mail = Mail()
print('1') // We Get here
msg = Message("Hello",
              sender="me@mydomain.com",
              recipients=["me@mydomain.com"])
print('2') // We get here
msg.body = 'Testing'
print('3') // We get here
mail.send(msg)
print('4') // This never gets call because I timeout on a 502 before this
```

I can tell I am not getting any fatal errors because the app stays working. However this fails with the 502. I have tried adding my email to the list of authorized senders but it doesn't seem to have helped.

I would appreciate any feedback. If I forced to use a 3rd party service to send mail it may cause me to move the project off of GAE.

Comment: Please post a stacktrace or more information about the error output. I believe the service you are using on localhost does not match what you have (or not) on the GAE instance.
Btw you need a mail service to send email from GAE. Take a look at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating#mail

Answer (score 0):

As Ivan posted on his comment, to send email from a GAE app you need to use a mail service. Right now there are 3 options for apps on a flexible environment: Mailgun, MailJet and SendGrid. Choose the one you see better for your app.

After setting up an account on the mail service you have chosen, you have to prepare your code by integrating the parts related to the mail service.

These tutorials should help you establish the mail service for your app:

- [Mailgun](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/sending-emails-with-mailgun)
- [MailJet](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/sending-emails-with-mailjet)
- [SendGrid](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/sending-emails-with-sendgrid)

Comment: Thanks yeah, as I read more into it I realized that. Is it limited to those 3 services or could I use any service that takes perhaps uses an API to allow me to send messages? The documentation doesn't say otherwise.

Comment: If you were using a standard environment for your app, you could use Python's own mail API to send your [email](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/), but since you are on the flexible environment, you can only use one of the mail services indicated above.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same error but on a virtual machine on the internet ( linode service ) and it turned out that it has some thing to do with rDNS and some domain name config that you have to set up for your Ip address to get things working correctly , check this

https://www.linode.com/community/questions/19082/i-just-created-my-first-linode-and-i-cant-send-emails-why